# How can I send a list of json objects as a parameter?

Tags: swift, alamofire

My JSON is:

```
[
  {
    "a": "1",
    "b": "2"
  }
]

let parameters: Parameters = [
                <here goes the JSON>
            ]


Alamofire.request(URL, method: .put, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers).validate().responseJSON
```

I know that the parameters are a dictionary of [String:AnyObject] but I need to pass it like in my first JSON

And I need to send this as the parameter, but I think I can only send an [String: AnyObject], or at least thats how the example works in the Alamofire migration guide, so my question is how to achieve this?
I'm using Alamofire 4

Comment: What do you mean by send as a parameter? Are you trying to extract the values and use them as params in a function call?

Answer (score 0):

I have used a library called SwiftyJSON and with that you can simply do:

```
     var jsonArray: JSON = [
     "array": [1, 2],
     "users": [
         [
             "id": 1,
             "info": [
             "name": "name1",
             "email": "email1"
          ],
          "nums": [123, 124, 125]
      ],
      [
        "id": 2,
        "info": [
            "name": "name2",
            "email": "email2"
        ],
        "nums": [12, 13, 14]
      ]
]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it like this:

```
var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: yourURL)!)
    request.httpBody = try! JSON(yourObject).rawData()
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    Alamofire.request(request).validate(statusCode: 200..<600).responseJSON { response in
        print("Response \(response)")
    }
```

JSON is a lib: [SwiftJSON](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON)